# GCPのBackup and DRのapplianceのdeployについて

Tags: google-cloud

GCPのBackup and DRの検証を実施をしております。
webコンソールより、Backup and DRにVPC情報等を設定し、applianceのdeloyについても問題なく行えたのですが、新規のVPCにapplianceをdeployしようとして、以下のスクリーンショットの赤枠の所をクリックして、新規のVPCにapplianceをdeployをしようとしたのですが、選択したプロジェクトとゾーンのVPCの情報が見えない状況です。

このようにBackup and DRの初期設定後に新規のVPCにapplianceをdeploy行いたい場合はどの様にすればよいのでしょうか。

[image: applianceの追加]

[image: applianceのdeploy]